# REST call in Spring-MVC

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I want to use a REST call in Spring MVC on my webapp and return a JSON, I've tried following mkyong's tutorial on this.http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-json-example/

However it isn't working, when I call

`http://localhost:8080/openRepairsClient/jan.peeters@student.kdg.be`

I get a 404 error.

This is my code:

```
@Controller
public class OpenRepairsRest {

    @Autowired
    private RepairService repairService;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/openRepairsClient/{username}")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Repair> openRepairsInJson(@PathVariable("username") String username) {
        List<Repair> openRepairs = null;
        try {
            openRepairs = repairService.findOpenRepairsByClient((Client) userService.getUser(username));
        } catch (UserServiceException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OpenRepairsRest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return openRepairs;
    }
}
```

And yes I'm sure the username exists, otherwise I would get a userservice exception.

My web.xml file:

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee                               http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <!-- welcome files -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <!-- context parameters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/jsf/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mytags.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- listeners -->
    <listener>
        <!-- Required for Faces to kick in -->
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Load applicationContext in ServletContextListener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Frontcontrollers -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>be.kdg.repaircafe.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <!--  Mappings -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>be.kdg.repaircafe.servlets.LogoutServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Authentication Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>LogoutServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/LogoutServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/error.jsp</location>
    </error-pag
```

e>

Comment: The double slash after the port in the URL is a typo?

Comment: Oh that slash; yes it's a typo, my bad

Comment: Between 8080 and openRepairsClient. `8080//openRepairsClient`

Comment: Are you sure that the server is running at 8080 and application is deployed sucessfully?

Comment: Yes, all other parts of my application run normally

Comment: What happens if you try `jan.peeters%40student.kdg.be` instead of `jan.peeters@student.kdg.be`

Comment: Did you try the url-encoded version of the '@' sign, %40?

Comment: Add Log after openRepairs is populated !

Comment: I have also noticed a different in your mapping annotations when comparing with the tutorial. Look @ RequestMapping on your openRepaidsInJson method and compare it with getShopInJson method on the tutorial

Comment: How about if you try `@RequestMapping(value = "/openRepairsClient/{username:.*}")`?

Comment: I suspect you are missing a context root in your URL (fraction of URL between `8080` and `/openRepairsClient`).

Comment: %40 doesn't work; '/' is my context root

Comment: What if you call `http://localhost:8080/openRepairsClient/jan.peeters@student.kdg.be/`, with extra slash at the end? I had some problems in the past due to this (it is a configuration in `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`, namely `useDefaultSuffixPattern`)

Comment: Is your class inside the folder specified on the component-scan annotation? If not, Spring won't load the class and the url won't be mapped

Comment: It's in the right package yes, adding an extra / didn't help unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is in the url, it appears that you forgot to write the project name and the word *rest*. Try with this url:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/rest/openRepairsClient/jan.peeters@student.kdg.be
```

You can try it with this simplified version of your code:

```
@Controller
public class OpenRepairsRest {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/openRepairsClient/{username}")
    public @ResponseBody
    List<Shop> openRepairsInJson(@PathVariable("username") String username) {

        Shop exampleShop = new Shop();
        exampleShop.setName("exampleName");
        exampleShop.setStaffName(new String[] { username });

        List<Shop> openShops = new ArrayList<Shop>();
        openShops.add(exampleShop);

        return openShops;
    }
}
```

Comment: The context root of my application is '/' as I configured it in my spring appcontext

Comment: Well, in that case it would be this url: http://localhost:8080/deployed_jar_name/openRepairsClient/jan.peeters@student.kdg.be  . You need to add the name of the deployed jar, that usually is the same as your project name

Comment: But I don't have this in any of my other webpages? I tried adding my projectname; this didn't work

Comment: In that case there may be a configuration problem in the url mapping. I have downloaded the example from Mkyong's website and added this class, and it works correctly on Tomcat 7. Please, could you show us your web.xml and other configuration files in order to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I added my web.xml, if you need any other files I'm happy to provide them

Comment: In your xml file you have this: `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` so you may need to add `rest` to the urls that you manage with Spring. Please, try with this url: `http://localhost:8080/rest/openRepairsClient/jan.peeters@student.kdg.be`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your app name in url, example: `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/openRepairsClient/jan.peeters@student.kdg.be`